# QT powershell error windows-build-qt-static.ps1

Tags: qt, static, compiler-errors

After 6-7 attempts to compile QT static version i used this article [Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/p/qtlmovie/code/ci/v1.2.16/tree/build/windows-build-qt-static.ps1?format=raw)
and again errors:
I have installed QT 5.7.

I downloaded 
[windows-build-qt-static.ps1](https://sourceforge.net/p/qtlmovie/code/ci/v1.2.16/tree/build/windows-build-qt-static.ps1?format=raw)  then  changing the necessary lines

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    $QtSrcUrl = "https://download.qt.io/snapshots/qt/5.8/5.8.0/latest_src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.7z",
    $QtStaticDir = "C:\Qt\Static",
    $QtVersion = "5.7",
    $MingwDir = "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\gcc.exe",
    [switch]$NoPause = $false
)
```

and the error is

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Admin> C:\Qt\windows-build-qt-static.ps1
Building static Qt version 5.7
Using MinGW from C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\gcc.exe
Downloading https://download.qt.io/snapshots/qt/5.8/5.8.0/latest_src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.7z ...
Expanding C:\Qt\Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.7z ...


7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 353390329 bytes (338 MiB)

--
Path = C:\Qt\Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 353390329
Headers Size = 1959904
Method = LZMA2:24
Solid = +
Blocks = 1

Everything is Ok

Folders: 17053
Files: 155016
Size:       1670093035
Compressed: 353390329
Patching C:\Qt\Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf ...
+ cd qtbase
+ C:\Qt\Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0\qtbase\configure.bat -top-level -static -debug-and-release -platfo
rm win32-g++ -prefix C:\Qt\Static\5.7         -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -qt-
sql-sqlite -no-openssl         -opensource -confirm-license         -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake te
sts
Please wait while bootstrapping configure ...
Perl not found in PATH. Aborting.
mingw32-make : The term 'mingw32-make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable pr
ogram. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Qt\windows-build-qt-static.ps1:170 char:5
+     mingw32-make -k -j4
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mingw32-make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

mingw32-make : The term 'mingw32-make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable pr
ogram. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Qt\windows-build-qt-static.ps1:171 char:5
+     mingw32-make -k install
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mingw32-make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Qt\Static\5.7\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf'.
At C:\Qt\windows-build-qt-static.ps1:178 char:6
+ "@ | Out-File -Append $File -Encoding Ascii
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

[image: perl path]

```
Please wait while bootstrapping configure ...
Perl not found in PATH. Aborting.
mingw32-make : The term 'mingw32-make' is not r .....
```

[image]

```
Out-File : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Qt\Static\5.7\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf'.
At C:\Qt\windows-build-qt-static.ps1:178 char:6
+ "@ | Out-File -Append $File -Encoding Ascii
```

Comment: Why do you have installed Qt 5.7 but try compile Qt 5.8?

Comment: @Edward https://download.qt.io/snapshots/qt/5.8/5.8.0/latest_src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.7z 
I want to compile with the following `configuration configure -platform win32-g++ -static -release` 
ie all the necessary .dll files are in .exe file     also with openssl support but at a later stage

Answer (score -1):

This `windows-build-qt-static.ps1` script worked for me a year ago.
Note at line 117, I just removed one `*` from path `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw*\bin\gcc.exe` between `Qt\` and `Tools`

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 
#  Copyright (c) 2013-2015, Thierry Lelegard
#  All rights reserved.
# 
#  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
#  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
# 
#  1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
#     this list of conditions and the following disclaimer. 
#  2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
#     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
#     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution. 
# 
#  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
#  AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
#  IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
#  ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
#  LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
#  CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
#  SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
#  INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
#  CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
#  ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF
#  THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
# 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

<#
 .SYNOPSIS

  Build a static version of Qt for Windows.

 .DESCRIPTION

  This scripts downloads Qt source code, compiles and installs a static version
  of Qt. It assumes that a prebuilt Qt / MinGW environment is already installed,
  typically in C:\Qt. This prebuilt environment uses shared libraries. It is
  supposed to remain the main development environment for Qt. This script adds
  a static version of the Qt libraries in order to allow the construction of
  standalone and self-sufficient executable.

  This script is typically run from the Windows Explorer.

  Requirements:
  - Windows PowerShell 3.0 or higher.
  - 7-zip.

 .PARAMETER QtSrcUrl

  URL of the Qt source file archive.
  By default, use the latest identified version.

 .PARAMETER QtStaticDir

  Root directory where the static versions of Qt are installed.
  By default, use C:\Qt\Static.

 .PARAMETER QtVersion

  The Qt version. By default, this script tries to extract the version number
  from the Qt source file name.

 .PARAMETER MingwDir

  Root directory of the MinGW prebuilt environment. By default, use the version
  which was installed by the prebuilt Qt environment.

 .PARAMETER NoPause

  Do not wait for the user to press <enter> at end of execution. By default,
  execute a "pause" instruction at the end of execution, which is useful
  when the script was run from Windows Explorer.
#>

[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    $QtSrcUrl = "http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.1/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.1.7z",
    $QtStaticDir = "C:\Qt\Static",
    $QtVersion = "",
    $MingwDir = "",
    [switch]$NoPause = $false
)

# PowerShell execution policy.
Set-StrictMode -Version 3

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main code
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Main
{
    # Check that 7zip is installed. We use it to expand the downloaded archive.
    [void] (Get-7zip)

    # Get Qt source file name from URL.
    $QtSrcFileName = Split-Path -Leaf $QtSrcUrl

    # If Qt version is not specified on the command line, try to extract the value.
    if (-not $QtVersion) {
        $QtVersion = $QtSrcFileName -replace "`.[^`.]*$",''
        $QtVersion = $QtVersion -replace 'qt-',''
        $QtVersion = $QtVersion -replace 'everywhere-',''
        $QtVersion = $QtVersion -replace 'opensource-',''
        $QtVersion = $QtVersion -replace 'src-',''
        $QtVersion = $QtVersion -replace '-src',''
    }
    Write-Output "Building static Qt version $QtVersion"

    # Qt installation directory.
    $QtDir = "$QtStaticDir\$QtVersion"

    # Get MinGW root directory, if not specified on the command line.
    if (-not $MingwDir) {
        # Search all instances of gcc.exe from C:\Qt prebuilt environment.
        $GccList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Qt\Tools\mingw*\bin\gcc.exe | ForEach-Object FullName | Sort-Object)
        if ($GccList.Length -eq 0) {
            Exit-Script "MinGW environment not found, no Qt prebuilt version?"
        }
        $MingwDir = (Split-Path -Parent (Split-Path -Parent $GccList[$GccList.Length - 1]))
    }
    Write-Output "Using MinGW from $MingwDir"

    # Build the directory tree where the static version of Qt will be installed.
    Create-Directory $QtStaticDir\src
    Create-Directory $QtDir

    # Download the Qt source package if not yet done.
    Download-File $QtSrcUrl $QtStaticDir\src\$QtSrcFileName

    # Directory of expanded packages.
    $QtSrcDir = "$QtStaticDir\src\$((Get-Item $QtStaticDir\src\$QtSrcFileName).BaseName)"

    # Expand archives if not yet done
    Expand-Archive $QtStaticDir\src\$QtSrcFileName $QtStaticDir\src $QtSrcDir

    # Patch Qt's mkspecs for static build.
    $File = "$QtSrcDir\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf"
    if (-not (Select-String -Quiet -SimpleMatch -CaseSensitive "# [QT-STATIC-PATCH]" $File)) {
        Write-Output "Patching $File ..."
        Copy-Item $File "$File.orig"
        @"

# [QT-STATIC-PATCH]
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static -static-libgcc
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -Os -momit-leaf-frame-pointer
DEFINES += QT_STATIC_BUILD
"@ | Out-File -Append $File -Encoding Ascii
    }

    # Set a clean path including MinGW.
    $env:Path = "$MingwDir\bin;$MingwDir\opt\bin"

    # Force English locale to avoid weird effects of tools localization.
    $env:LANG = "en"

    # Set environment variable QT_INSTALL_PREFIX. Documentation says it should be
    # used by configure as prefix but this does not seem to work. So, we will
    # also specify -prefix option in configure.
    $env:QT_INSTALL_PREFIX = $QtDir

    # Configure, compile and install Qt.
    Push-Location $QtSrcDir
    & $env:SystemRoot\System32\cmd.exe /c "configure.bat -static -debug-and-release -platform win32-g++ -prefix $QtDir `
        -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -qt-sql-sqlite -no-openssl `
        -opensource -confirm-license `
        -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests"
    mingw32-make -k -j4
    mingw32-make -k install
    Pop-Location

    # Patch Qt's installed mkspecs for static build of application.
    $File = "$QtDir\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf"
    @"
CONFIG += static
"@ | Out-File -Append $File -Encoding Ascii

    Exit-Script
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# A function to exit this script. The Message parameter is used on error.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Exit-Script ([string]$Message = "")
{
    $Code = 0
    if ($Message -ne "") {
        Write-Output "ERROR: $Message"
        $Code = 1
    }
    if (-not $NoPause) {
        pause
    }
    exit $Code
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Silently create a directory.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Create-Directory ([string]$Directory)
{
    [void] (New-Item -Path $Directory -ItemType "directory" -Force)
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Download a file if not yet present.
# Warning: If file is present but incomplete, do not download it again.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Download-File ([string]$Url, [string]$OutputFile)
{
    $FileName = Split-Path $Url -Leaf
    if (-not (Test-Path $OutputFile)) {
        # Local file not present, start download.
        Write-Output "Downloading $Url ..."
        try {
            $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
            $webclient.DownloadFile($Url, $OutputFile)
        }
        catch {
            # Display exception.
            $_
            # Delete partial file, if any.
            if (Test-Path $OutputFile) {
                Remove-Item -Force $OutputFile
            }
            # Abort
            Exit-Script "Error downloading $FileName"
        }
        # Check that the file is present.
        if (-not (Test-Path $OutputFile)) {
            Exit-Script "Error downloading $FileName"
        }
    }
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get path name of 7zip, abort if not found.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Get-7zip
{
    $Exe = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    if (-not (Test-Path $Exe)) {
        $Exe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    }
    if (-not (Test-Path $Exe)) {
        Exit-Script "7-zip not found, install it first, see http://www.7-zip.org/"
    }
    $Exe
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Expand an archive file if not yet done.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Expand-Archive ([string]$ZipFile, [string]$OutDir, [string]$CheckFile)
{
    # Check presence of expected expanded file or directory.
    if (-not (Test-Path $CheckFile)) {
        Write-Output "Expanding $ZipFile ..."
        & (Get-7zip) x $ZipFile "-o$OutDir" | Select-String -Pattern "^Extracting " -CaseSensitive -NotMatch
        if (-not (Test-Path $CheckFile)) {
            Exit-Script "Error expanding $ZipFile, $OutDir\$CheckFile not found"
        }
    }
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Execute main code.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. Main
```

Comment: `mingw32-make : The term 'mingw32-make' is not recognized as the name of a ...` - because you run your script without Qt environment.